# Correct way to vectorise tensorflow step

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, vectorization, tensor

I'm working with 4 dimensional tensors and need to do a couple of calculations that work like the following example. Take `A` to be a tensor with shape `(6,64,64,64)`. I want to use the function `tf.where` to obtain the voxels of each `(64,64,64)` volume that has a value larger than `0.75`. The only way I have managed to do this is like this:

```
X = tf.convert_to_tensor([tf.where(A[i,:,:,:] > 0.75) for i in range(A.shape[0])]
```

This seems to be a very crude solution. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question completely, but you might take a look at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn to apply the tf.where to your A (you'll most likely need to wrap that in a helper function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with what you are trying to do is that it requires that each `(64, 64, 64)` volume has the same number of values greater than 0.75. If that is the case, you could just do the following:

```
X = tf.reshape(tf.where(A > 0.75)[:, 1:], (A.shape[0], -1, A.shape.ndims - 1))
```

But if that is not the case, you just cannot have a tensor like that because the second dimension would need to have multiple sizes.

Comment: Yes, I ended up reaching the same conclusion. Thanks for the input!